# Problem:: Arithmetic Expression by String operation in C

Tags: c, math, expression

> Objective: Here the codes should
>     read any arbitrary long arithmetic
>     expression like, 233+200. Then it
>     should print in the postfix and prefix
>     formats and calculate it i.e 433.
>
> ```
> Problems: output shows anomalous data like 98, 101 etc. I think there
> might be any mistake in the code.
> please have a look and let me know it.
> ```

```
#include<stdio.h>
void copy(char* t, char* s, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        t[i]=s[i];
    t[n]='\n';
}
int fix(char* s, int length, int task)
{
    int i;
    for( i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if((s[i]=='+')||(s[i]=='-'))
        {
            char s1[i+1];
            char s2[length-i];
            copy(s1,s,i);
            copy(s2,s+i+1,length-i-1);
            if(task==2)
            {
                return fix(s1,i,task)+fix(s2,i,task);
            }
            else
            {
                return fix(s1,i,task)-fix(s2,length-1,task);
            }
            if(task==0)printf("%c",s[i]);;
            fix(s1,i,task);
            fix(s2,length-i-1,task);
            if(task==1)printf("%c",s[i]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    char s[80];
    int i;
    for(i=0;(s[i]=getchar())!='\n';i++);
    fix(s,i,0);
    printf("\n");
    fix(s,i,1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n",fix(s,i,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Can you provide us with some examples of the exact output that you are seeing and the exact input that you used to generate it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, there are a few problems in the code. We don't generally run a free debugging service here, but for starters, what is:

```
(s,i,0);
```

supposed to be doing?

Comment: sorry it was fix(s,i,0)..just notepad copy mistake.

Comment: @Gorge:  Do a copy-paste of the code, not a manual copy.  If you retype into the question box, you're likely to type what you subconsciously know is right rather than what's there.  We've seen a lot of code that couldn't possibly get the erroneous output supplied.

Comment: sorry i dont understand you??

Answer (score 0):

In the `copy` function, where is the `ending null character` after contents of `s` have been copied into `t`? Terminating a c string with `\n` instead of `\0` is wrong. All c strings are terminated by a null character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through this code in a debugger?  I think doing so would make it much more clear that your program is not doing what you think it is doing.

One potential problem is that the code following the `if(task==2) { ... } else { ... }` block in the `fix` function will never be executed.  Both the `if` and `else` cases contain `return` statments, so execution will never make it to that code.

Also, your loop `for(i=0;(s[i]=getchar())!='\n';i++);` in `main` has no protection against writing past the end of array `s`.  This line of code is essentially the same as the standard library function `gets`, which has the same problem.

What compiler are you using?  What compiler options are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the purpose of task 0 and task 1 are, but you are not using the + or - operator in the input at all.  What you should be doing is something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fix(char* s) {
  int v=0;
  for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++) {
    char op=s[i];
    switch (op) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
      // We encountered a math operator.  
      s[i]='\0';
      if      (op=='+') return fix(s) + fix(s+i+1);
      else if (op=='-') return fix(s) - fix(s+i+1);
      break;
    case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': 
    case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9': case '0':
      // This is part of the value.
      v*=10;
      v+=s[i]-'0';
      break;
    default:
      // Ignore non-operators and non values.
      break;
    }
  }
  // Return the value
  return v;
}

int main(){
    char s[80];
    int i;
    for(i=0;(s[i]=getchar())!='\n';i++);
    s[i]='\0';
    printf("%d\n",fix(s));
    return 0;
}
```